# How to use each() to loop through and get values?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.4.3.

I have some divs that have microdata in them and I am trying to access them via jQuery in a loop.  These divs will output much like rows and columns.

```
<div data-row="1" data-col="1">
<div data-row="1" data-col="2">
<div data-row="1" data-col="3">

<div data-row="2" data-col="1">
<div data-row="2" data-col="2">
<div data-row="2" data-col="3">

<div data-row="3" data-col="1">
<div data-row="3" data-col="2">
<div data-row="3" data-col="3">
```

I am trying to loop through each row and get the maximum height of each div in that row (although I am not doing exactly that with this  code).  With this code, I just want to be able to loop through how ever many rows there are.

This works and will produce three alerts of "1":

```
// ACCESS THE HEIGHT OF EACH CELL
$("[data-row='1']").each(function() {
    var R = $(this).attr("data-row");
    alert(R);
});
```

What I expect to see when this runs is three alerts of "1", followed by three alerts of "2", followed by three alerts of "3". I do not get any errors when the code "runs". No alerts are thrown.  This does NOT work:

```
$("[data-row>='1']").each(function() {
    var R = $(this).attr("data-row");
    alert(R);
});
```

What's wrong with this piece of code?  Why is it not finding any rows that have data-row value of 1 or greater?

Comment: you cant do a greater than when it comes to strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML attributes are read as strings, not as ints.  Also, [according to the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), attribute values should be quoted in selectors (as they are strings).

That is why `$("[data-row=1]")` doesn't work, and `$("[data-row='1']")` does.

`$("[data-row>='1']")` doesn't work because `>=` is not an attribute selector.

To get divs with `data-row >= 1`, you're gonna have to use `filter`, and check the value of `data-row` (p.s. you can do `$("[data-row]")` to get all divs with that attribute regardless of value).

```
$("[data-row]").filter(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).data('row'), 10) >= 1;
})
```

NOTE: jQuery can use `.data` to get `data-*` attributes, instead of `.attr`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thorough explanation! I wish more people took the time to be as helpful as you.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("[data-row]").each(function() {
    var R = $(this).attr("data-row");
    alert(R);
});
```

Because `data-row` is a whole attribute, you can specify just that to loop over all of them irrespective of what value it has.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing issues because `>=` is not a valid CSS Attribute Selector comparison. If you want to run the method for any element that has the attribute set, you could try:

```
$('[data-row]').each(function(){
    var R = $(this).attr('data-row');
    alert(R);
});
```

To see the valid attribute selectors, check out [W3 - Attribute Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe jQuery has a selector for a value greater than or equal to something. I think what you want is this:

```
$("[data-row]").each(function() {
    var R = $(this).attr("data-row");
    alert(R);
});
```

Comment: I got six answers within two minutes, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`$("[data-row='1']")` Only the first three rows match this selector.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('[data-row=1], [data-row=2], [data-row=3]').each(function() {
    var R = $(this).attr("data-row");
    alert(R);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code like this. I will never know how many rows or columns will be coming out of the database.  Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah...probably not the best solution if you're going to have more than those.

Answer (score -2):

The correct signature is:

```
$("[data-row='1']").each(function(index, item) {
});
```

Sorry, forgot them, it was more the anonymous function signature that needed correcting.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having quotes around the value, or excluding the unused parameters.

Comment: According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), attribute values **must** be quoted.

Comment: @Rocket: I [filed a bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11300) the other day with respect to the `:contains()` selector, since it made reference to `attribute` selectors not needing quotes around simple values. The upshot was that they changed the docs for their attribute selectors to make quotes optional in that case. Seems that they didn't change that page. I'll send another note in the bug report.